# Bootstrap force rounding of input-group element with form validation

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, bootstrap-5

I would like to combine Bootstrap 5's [`input-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/input-group/#multiple-inputs) with [`form validation`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/#custom-styles). However, the last `input-group` element is squared and not rounded when validation message is present. Is it possible to force round it?

Bonus: is it possible to provide a different validation *message* for `first` & `last` name in my example below?

```js
(() => {
  'use strict'
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <p/>
  <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text">First and last name</span>
        <input type="text" name="first" pattern="^\w{5}$" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="text" name="last" pattern="^\w{5}$" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          upto 5 alphanumeric char only
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `.has-validation` class to the `div` with the `.input-group`  class.

> To fix [issues with border radius](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25110), input groups require an additional .has-validation class.

```js
(() => {
  'use strict'
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br/>
  <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group has-validation">
        <span class="input-group-text">First and last name</span>
        <input type="text" name="first" pattern="^\w{5}$" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="text" name="last" pattern="^\w{5}$" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          upto 5 alphanumeric char only
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to provide separate feedback message for each input?